# I want to set a value of a a new record form field in event procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want  a command button to open a new record of a form with one of its fields to have a value of a combo box from another form.

Inventory is the form name while PRODUCT_CODE is a field name in the form 
Combo_Product_number is a combobox name of another form.

So I want the form to openwith a product_code value field to have been filled with the value of the combobox.

while the rest of the fields are empty.

I am pretty new to access

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "FRM_Inventory_A03"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Forms!FRM_Inventory_A03!PRODUCT_CODE='& Me!Combo_Product_number & "'"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made up 2 forms. In `frm1` there is a combobox named `Combo_Product_number`.

Got a second form named `FRM_Inventory_A03`.

[image]

In `frm1` there is a combobox with numbers, and a button named `Command5`. When clicked, the button will open the form `FRM_Inventory_A03` in **[acFormAdd mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acformopendatamode)**

In `FRM_Inventory_A03` there are 3 fields, but one of them is named `PRODUCT_CODE`

The code of the button is:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "FRM_Inventory_A03", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acDialog
End Sub
```

Now, when you open the form `FRM_Inventory_A03` to add a new record, you want to assign the value of the combobox `Combo_Product_number` to control `PRODUCT_CODE`.

To do this, you need to open the form `FRM_Inventory_A03` in Design Mode, select control `PRODUCT_CODE` and in the properties, data tab, in property `DefaultValue`, type this:

`=[Forms]![frm1]![Combo_Product_number]`

[image]

This will pass the value of the combobox `Combo_Product_number` to control `PRODUCT_CODE`.

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the product number to the form's `OpenArgs` parameter. It's the very last parameter of Variant type and it's optional.

Passing the parameter:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria, , , Me.Combo_Product_number.Value
```

Handling the parameter is the Form's Load event. You just need to check for Null to avoid errors.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Not IsNull(OpenArgs) Then PRODUCT_CODE.Value = OpenArgs
End Sub
```

Comment: Combo_Product_number is a field from another form entirely.  Also, the inventory form has another way of opening from another button.    The command button I am working on is meant to specifically open the form in my disred way of filling the product code automatically

Comment: I dont know how your code is structured, but you can set the product number in a standard module through a public property and then you can access it from anywhere in the app. Or even set it in a `TempVar`.

Comment: can you please assist me with the line of code in order to try this? It will mean so much to me.Thank you

Comment: To add to the TempVars: `TempVars.Add "ProductCode", Me.Combo_Product_number.Value` and to retrieve the value: `TempVars!ProductCode`. These are global so you have access to them from anywhere in your app.

Comment: from where do I do this?