# How to copy a date from one form to another in ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I am creating an inward/outward courier register for my office. I've two forms: main form and second form based on main form.

I want to copy date field from main form to my second form by default. How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean second form is a dependent subform? Why would you need to duplicate date into subform record? Isn't there already a PK/FK relationship?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904927/i-want-to-set-a-value-of-a-a-new-record-form-field-in-event-procedure/57924234#57924234) you can see how to take the value of a combobox to another form. You can modify it to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: How you pass data depends on the way things work.
Is the second form a sub-form (open all the time, in a control on the main form) or is it a detail form that opens when you click something (like a button)?